# Xamarin Forms Shell Navigation using Route

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I navigate using the route defined in the XAML...
I want to navigate from 'upcoming' to 'servicedetail' route. So far I have been able to navigate using the below, but don't see the back button (on-screen) on the servicedetail page. Each time I hit the back button (physical back button), it closes the application

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//servicedetail?param={serviceDetail.Id}");
```

This is how I have setup the pages so far...

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Unison" Route="main"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <Tab Title="My Services" Icon="icon.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Upcoming" Route="upcoming" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UpcomingServicePage}" />

        <ShellContent Title="Past" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PastServicePage}" />

    </Tab>


</FlyoutItem>
<TabBar>
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent Route="servicedetail"
              Title="Team" 
              Icon="info.png"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ServiceDetailPage}" />

        <ShellContent Route="servicedetail2"
              Title="Songlist"
              Icon="info.png"
              ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ServiceDetailPage}" />

    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Comment: How did you click the back button when you say you can't see the button? Did you implement the [back-button-behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior)? When the application closes, any error? Can you share the stacktrace.

Comment: Hey @JackHua-MSFT, I don't see a Back Button on the screen. The back button that I'm referring to is the physical back button on Android

Comment: Can you answer my other two questions? Also official sample is here: [Xaminals](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals/)

Comment: No error when the app closes. Behaves exactly like there are no more pages to go back-to, so closes

Comment: i went through the Xaminals example. Basically I want to do a similar "monkeysdetail" page routing that is done in Xaminals. But on this detail page, I want to have a tab bar navigation. Do I need to go back to using a TabbedPage ?

Comment: @AmitPhilips if I'm understanding your intent correctly. Currently you can't create a navigation stack between different routes like this out of the box. You could customize BackButtonBehavior, change out the icon, and provide backbutton command. You could also provide a BackButtonBehavior that just provides your own command and then when they hit the physical back button do a navigation so it doesn't close the app. We are currently figuring out the best way to articulate more complex hierarchical navigation between Shell Elements https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6139

Comment: Thanks @ShaneNeuville for your comment. Glad to hear that there is discussion around it.
Meanwhile will try to provide a customized BackButtonBehavior and get back to this thread with my progress

Comment: Hey @ShaneNeuville, i tried the Shell.BackbuttonBehavior to just display an Alert box when the back button was pressed and I'm getting a... "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error for it. Any idea what is causing the error ?

Comment: @AmitPhilips I'm hoping to get most of the quirks with BackButtonBehavior resolved over here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6762

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the route only on the `ShellContent` and it should be considered as the root page in the navigationPage and you can not pop back anymore.

Try to modify your xaml to add `route` to `TabBar` and `Tab`:

```
<TabBar Route="tabbarTest">
    <Tab Route="TabTest">
        <ShellContent Route="servicedetail"
          Title="Team" 
          Icon="info.png"
          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ServiceDetailPage}" />

        <ShellContent Route="servicedetail2"
          Title="Songlist"
          Icon="info.png"
          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ServiceDetailPage}" />

    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

And navigate to the page `servicedetail1` by:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//tabbarTest/TabTest/servicedetail?param={serviceDetail.Id}");
```

If you want to go to `servicedetail2`:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//tabbarTest/TabTest/servicedetai2?param={serviceDetail.Id}");
```

Read the document about [navigation#register-routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes) to understand how it works.

> All items in the Shell hierarchy have a route associated with them. If
>   a route is not set by the developer, the route is generated at
>   runtime. However, generated routes are not guaranteed to be consistent
>   across different application sessions.

Comment: Tried this but it is still the same... I guess the app closes as it is trying to go back from servicedetail > tabtest > tabbartest... which is actually not a page.

Was hoping I would be able to go back from servicedetail > main > upcoming but that is in a completely different route

Comment: @AmitPhilips So you want to click the upcoming in the flyout menu and go to servicedetail. Then you hope there is a back button on the servicedetail that can go back to your detailPage which contains two Tabs?

Comment: Yea I have a list on UpcomingServicePage. If I tap on one of the items, it needs to redirect me to ServiceDetailPage. On hitting back/back-button, I want to redirect back to the list on UpcomingServicePage.

The reason I put ServiceDetailPage as part of the shell xaml page is because of the <TabBar> feature instead of using the Tabbed Page. Using TabbedPage with Shell is causing distortion on the page

Answer (score 0):

> await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//servicedetail?param={serviceDetail.Id}");

the above route will replace the stack, using // to navigate to servicedetail will erase the stack so previous page history is deleted from the stack.
Once you click on back button the application will be exited as the stack is empty.

[see shell navigation documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation)